# Getting the latest version of MySQL for EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

For my website I am using MySQL for EF6.  When I set it up, I was told to use the 6.8.3 version, so I have `MySql.Data v6.8.3` and `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 v6.8.3` that I installed via Nuget.

Here's the values from my packages.config file:

```
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" version="6.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

However, I've noticed that there are more up to date versions and I'm concerned that there may be bugs in the older versions.  For example, [MySql.Data is up to version 6.9.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)... should I be using that?

If so, how do I update them to the latest versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6.9.5 is supported (www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity), so just go to Manage Nuget Packages in Visual Studio and click Updates (or use the console).

Comment: Thank you, I just updated it via NUGET Package Manager Console and all seems to be OK.